# Enable specific StackOverflow/StackExchange site newsletter after banishing the prompt to do so

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, newsletter, user-experience

What I hope is a simple question:

I use several StackExchange sites (hereafter, "SE sites"), including *StackOverflow, Superuser, Serverfault,* and *English Language and Usage.* For all of these, a prompt will occasionally display in the right column allowing the user to sign up to that site's associated weekly newsletter.

There appears to be some predefined criteria, potentially in the ad revolver, that prevents this prompt from displaying for some users. This appears to only hold true for sites that I have an established reputation and pool of search tags built into. I admit to not performing cross-browser verification of these results, so if you have more information on these criteria, please share them in the comments.

After some aggravation with imprecise Google hits, I was able to locate https://stackexchange.com/newsletters. This isn't a desirable solution to a common use case, however; that is, users that wish to add themselves to a specific newsletter after the prompt reminding them to do so has disappeared will either need to be cognizant of this link from the outset or need to turn to their favorite search engine, fighting through several imprecise results that this question may help address.

I would thus recommend two simple changes. On the bottom bar, please add a context-sensitive link, "newsletter," that attempts to add the user to the newsletter for the SE site that they are currently browsing. Additionally, I would suggest increasing the visibility of the newsletter subscription page in the user profile, as this is the most intuitive location to find this information.

Do you know if this is the correct approach to the problem? Is there something I've missed in the general StackExchange user experience that better supports this use case?

Comment: The newsletter ad is always visible if you go to edit your user profile on a site.